# Alternative syntax for splitting a JavaScript string into an array of characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I wanted to split a string into individual characters for output, and I thought about using string.split("") to convert my string into an array, but I found that it wasn't necessary. Look at this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "Javascript">
var vx = "FGHIFKL"
for (var i = 0; var i<vx.length; i++)
{
document.write(vx[i]); // Outputs FGHIFKL
} 
</script>
```

It seems you can access strings as if they were arrays by using vx[0] without explicitly using
 str.split. Because vx[0] = F, vx[1] = G, etc. Is this syntax generally allowed, or even recommended for use in browsers? And how come this even works? I didn't know you could do something like this until today. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes. string is treated as a character array, esp in ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you can use `[]` notation to pull individual characters out of JS strings.

Keep in mind that this doesn't work in the older IE's (7 definitely fails, and I believe 8 does as well).

You can use `charAt` for a cross-browser solution

```
"asdf".charAt(1) === "s";
```

Answer (score 1):

A String in JavaScript is a sequence of characters.

There are two ways to get to individual characters in a string.

1. The `charAt` method: `str.charAt(n)`
2. ECMAScript 5 introduced a way to treat strings as an array-like object: `str[n]`

On the other hand, `split` method returns a new array which is an array of *strings* separated into substrings. Interesting to note is the fact that if separator parameter to the `split` method is an empty string, the string is converted to an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Reading numerical indicies of strings is a reliable feature of javascript as of ES5. These index properties are not quite the same as on arrays in that they are not writable or configurable.  Check out the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) for strings and the ECMAScript Language Specification sections [15.5.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5) and [15.5.5.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5.2) for more information.